# How do I get my pc's windows Workgroup name in python

Tags: python, windows, network-programming, workgroup

I'm trying to find my workGroup name in python,
does anybody know a function for that?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the exact thing and I could not find a direct way through Python.  Instead I had to use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to run a `PowerShell` command:

```py
import subprocess

domain = subprocess.run(["powershell.exe", "(Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
domain = domain.stdout.strip()

print(domain)
```

You can also just make it a one-liner by appending `stdout.strip()` directly to `subprocess()`:

```py
import subprocess

domain = subprocess.run(["powershell.exe", "(Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True).stdout.strip()

print(domain)
```

Result:

```py
"mydomain.com"    # domain-joined computer
# OR
"workgroup"    # workgroup name
```

I've included the string method `strip()` to remove the trailing `\n` characters that `STDOUT` produces.

The PowerShell command `(Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain` retrieves either the domain name that the computer is joined to, or just the workgroup name if it's not joined to a domain.

NOTE:
I saw older suggestions on StackOverflow using the PowerShell command `Get-WmiObject`, which only works with **PowerShell 5.1**.  [Microsoft recommends using the newer `Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/breaking-changes-ps6#wmi-v1-cmdlets), which works with PowerShell 5.1 and newer (ie: PowerShell Core)

Answer (score 0):

```
import wmi
wmi_os = wmi.Win32_ComputerSystem()[0]
print(wmi_os.Workgroup)
```

You also can go further and take a look at `print(wmi_os.__dict__['properties'].keys())`

```
dict_keys(['AdminPasswordStatus', 'AutomaticManagedPagefile', 'AutomaticResetBootOption', 'AutomaticResetCapability', 'BootOptionOnLimit', 'BootOptionOnWatchDog', 'BootROMSupported', 'BootStatus', 'BootupState', 'Caption', 'ChassisBootupState', 'ChassisSKUNumber', 'CreationClassName', 'CurrentTimeZone', 'DaylightInEffect', 'Description', 'DNSHostName', 'Domain', 'DomainRole', 'EnableDaylightSavingsTime', 'FrontPanelResetStatus', 'HypervisorPresent', 'InfraredSupported', 'InitialLoadInfo', 'InstallDate', 'KeyboardPasswordStatus', 'LastLoadInfo', 'Manufacturer', 'Model', 'Name', 'NameFormat', 'NetworkServerModeEnabled', 'NumberOfLogicalProcessors', 'NumberOfProcessors', 'OEMLogoBitmap', 'OEMStringArray', 'PartOfDomain', 'PauseAfterReset', 'PCSystemType', 'PCSystemTypeEx', 'PowerManagementCapabilities', 'PowerManagementSupported', 'PowerOnPasswordStatus', 'PowerState', 'PowerSupplyState', 'PrimaryOwnerContact', 'PrimaryOwnerName', 'ResetCapability', 'ResetCount', 'ResetLimit', 'Roles', 'Status', 'SupportContactDescription', 'SystemFamily', 'SystemSKUNumber', 'SystemStartupDelay', 'SystemStartupOptions', 'SystemStartupSetting', 'SystemType', 'ThermalState', 'TotalPhysicalMemory', 'UserName', 'WakeUpType', 'Workgroup'])
```

Some of them might be useful for you